# Работа с сетью в командной строке Windows

Tags: cmd, arp, tracert

Возник ряд различных вопросов, связанных с командной строкой в *Windows*.
Прошу Вас исправить, если я не так что-то понимаю или ответить - если поставлен вопрос.

1) **Определить находится ли устройство в NAT**

Прописываем ***ipconfig***. Смотрим на IP - адрес. Он должен быть в одном из диапазонов: 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255, 172.(16 - 31).0.0 - 172.(16 - 31).255.255, 192.168.(0 - 255).0 - 192.168.(0 - 255).255. Если да -он локальный, а используя
2ip.ru,можно увидеть адрес,под которым мы в интернете видны. Так? И можно ли таким же образом определить двойной NAT?

2) **Вывести метрику**

Вводим ***route print***. И это все? Не совсем понимаю, что такое метрика. Количество пройденных шлюзов? Объясните, пожалуйста, как это корректно сделать и что будут обозначать пункты выведенной таблицы.

3) **Вычислить количество прыжков к устройству, на котором стоит тот или иной ресурс**

Вводим ***tracert ("сайт")***. Потом, воспользовавшись 2ip.ru/whois/, можно определить место расположения всех маршрутизаторов на пути?

4) **Использование команды "arp"**

***arp -a*** - выведет arp - таблицу (в ней находятся ip-шники и MAC - адреса компов, например, которые пинговались?). Потом мы можем удалить какую-то запись (***arp -d***), если или же добавить статическую запись (***arp -s***)?
Но ведь запись в таблице могут сами удаляться, если маршрутизация динамическая или я что-то путаю? И я могу написать любую статическую запись в таблицу?
Очень прошу вас ответить, а если считаете, что вопросы слишком глупые - не кидайте сразу тухлыми яйцами, а постарайтесь объяснить, я ведь только учусь.

Comment: Во-первых, заголовок вопроса не соответствует самому вопросу, во-вторых, данный вопрос следовало бы разделить на несколько.

Comment: я бы посоветовал изучить материалы по CCNA, куча сетевых вопросов отвалится :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Верно. Если IP-адрес компьютера принадлежит диапазону так называемых "серых" адресов (10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16), то для доступа к сети Интернет используется NAT. Это связано с тем, что "серые" адреса предназначены специально для локальных сетей и не маршрутизируются в глобальных сетях (то есть недоступны). Есть несколько исключений, но их можно не принимать во внимание.

Однако, не всё так просто. Если ваш IP-адрес не входит в "серый" диапазон, то с большой вероятностью NAT'а нет. Но может и есть. Никто не запрещает выдать вам "белый" адрес, который затем выпустить через NAT. Так могут работать "кривые" сети. Кроме того, блок 100.64.0.0/10 вроде бы "белых" адресов на самом деле используется вместе с NAT, это "псевдосерые" адреса, которые могут использовать для своих внутренних сетей только интернет-провайдеры. (См. [RFC 6598](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598).)

Что же касается двойного NAT, то его таким образом не определить. В общем случае ни `ipconfig`, ни `tracert`, ни 2ip не дадут ответа на вопрос о наличии двойного NAT.

2. Метрика маршрута - это его приоритет. Чем меньше метрика, тем выше приоритет. Метрика вступает в действие, если до какого-то хоста можно "достучаться" по нескольким путям. Будет выбран путь с наименьшей метрикой. В общем случае с числом пройденных шлюзов не связано, хотя некоторые протоколы динамической маршрутизации вычисляют метрику исходя из числа промежуточных маршрутизаторов.

Столбцы таблицы, выводимой `route print` достаточно просты. Первые два (сетевой адрес и маска сети) описывают диапазон адресов, третий (адрес шлюза) - адрес маршрутизатора, через который доступен этот диапазон, четвёртый (интерфейс) - адрес интерфейса локальной машины, с которого следует посылать пакет маршрутизатору, пятый (метрика) - описанная выше метрика.

3. Верно. Трассировка (`tracert`) показывает маршрутизаторы, через которые проходит пакет. Но она не всегда даёт правильный результат. например, туннели (VPN и т.п.) скрывают маршрутизаторы между клиентом и сервером - независимо от реального числа маршрутизаторов между клиентом и сервером вторым хопом почти всегда будет VPN-сервер.

Некоторую информацию о промежуточных маршрутизаторах 2ip, конечно, даст. Но и здесь есть подводные камни, а именно - "серые" адреса, которые могут возникнуть при маршрутизации даже в глобальной сети. Существует мнение, что их там быть не должно, но оно неверное. Маршрутизаторы внутри одного провайдера вполне могут общаться и через "серую" подсеть. Логика тут в том, что за пределы провайдера они не выдут, а внутри своей сети провайдера мало что ограничивает.

4. А вот здесь Вы путаете. ARP-таблица не имеет отношения к маршрутизации. Никакого. Она работает на другом уровне. ARP-таблица - это соответствие между IP- и MAC-адресом. Общение внутри одного сегмента сети (broadcast-домена) идёт по MAC-адресам сетевых карт. Пакет отсылается именно на MAC-адрес. А протокол ARP ответственен за соответствие IP и MAC.

P.S. Прошу не задавать уточняющих вопросов, потому что изначальный вопрос слишком обширен. Если что-то непонятно, задайте новый вопрос, возможно, указав в его тексте на этот.

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ. Все понятно объяснили, вот только не понял как понять есть ли двойной NAT?

Comment: есть какие-то способы? где-то читал,что можно спомощью **tracert** и **ipconfig**

Comment: @MuscledBoy При помощи `tracert` и `ipconfig` двойной NAT  определяется только в самых простейших ситуациях. Вот пример: https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT203147. Фактически задача сводится к следующему: я знаю, что у меня есть роутер с NAT и я хочу знать, есть ли NAT у провайдера. Для этого мы просто проверяем на "серость" адрес второго хопа. Но сети часто бывают намного более сложными. Если двойной NAT реализован внутри сети провайдера, то его детектировать невероятно сложно.